# of the same vs. of same

Tags: definite-article

> Fisher is right to note that Australia’s political culture is simply
>   more advanced on these matters than ours. But the problem, as I see
>   it, is more public than political. In Australia, I don’t know what
>   came first: the chicken of political maturity or the egg of public
>   expectations **of same**. But I do know that in Canada, our political
>   immaturity isn’t a glitch or anomaly. It’s an entirely predictable and
>   understandable, if unacceptable, byproduct of the Canadian public’s
>   low literacy on military matters.

[Australia is a grown-up country. We aren’t](http://news.nationalpost.com/full-comment/matt-gurney-australia-is-a-grown-up-country-we-arent)

Does putting '**the**' in front of '**same**' make a difference?

Comment: Related: [English Definite Article “the” with “Same”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/221580/9161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, using **the** before **same** makes no difference

> the chicken of political maturity or the egg of public expectation **of same**
>   the chicken of political maturity or the egg of public expectation **of** ***the*** **same**
>
> *the chicken of political maturity or the egg of public expectation of (political maturity)*

in both, **same** is understood to refer to political maturity in Matt Gurney's example of a
Chicken and Egg problem