# English Definite Article "the" with "Same"

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

I know we often use the English article "the" before nouns. But I have noticed this is not always true.

According to the Oxford dictionary, "Same" is used as Adjective, Pronoun, and Adverb.

Oxford Dictionary Link: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/same

**As Adjective:**
All examples in the Oxford dictionary use "the" before nouns when "same" is used as an adjective. A few examples from the dictionary are below.

> Examples:
>   1. She was saying **the same** thing over and over.
>   2. I'm **the same** age as you are.
>   3. He's worked at **the same** place for quite a few years.
>   4. They drank out of **the same** glass.

*Question 1:*
So, can I say this is universally true? Whenever "same" is used as an adjective, "the" is placed before it.

**As Pronoun and Adverb:**
When it is used as a pronoun or adverb, in some examples "the" is placed before it but in some, not.

A few examples from the dictionary are below when used as a pronoun.

> Examples:
>   1. I'll resign and encourage everyone else to do **the same**.
>   2. there are several brands and they're not all **the same**.
>   3. All age groups are welcome to participate and sponsorship of **same** would be very welcome.
>   4. It turns out that the head of **same** is a prominent member of the Australian Kurdish community.

A few examples from the dictionary are below when used as an Adverb.

> Examples:
>   1. treating women **the same** as men 
>   2. he gave me five dollars, **same** as usual.

*Question 2:*
As from the above examples, when "same" is used as a pronoun or adverb, in some cases, "the" is placed and in some, not. Can someone explain to me this?

I have also visited this StackExchange link, but it does not answer my question [Does the adjective 'same' ALWAYS have the definite article 'the'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/does-the-adjective-same-always-have-the-definite-article-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- … and sponsorship of same would be very welcome.
- It turns out that the head of same is a prominent member …

In these two examples, *same* is equivalent to ‘the aforementioned’, without implying similarity to anything else.  This is a stuffy formal usage, smelling of legalese, so I wouldn't bother trying to compare it with other senses of *same*.

(It is also sometimes used with the article.)